# Destroying Instantiated Clone Components Breaks Original Game Object Components?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Maybe im missing something obvious but to keep it short. I have working code for a character. When you "dash" I want to leave behind an after-image type effect, by cloning the player, removing its unneeded components and then applying a shader. Issue is as soon as I instantiate the clone the original player stops functioning (cant move etc). It still has all its components and everything as normal, and the clone does get the correct components removed. But it still breaks. As soon as I remove that line, its back to normal. Any ideas?

This is the only relevant code in the script that instantiates the clone.

```
private void DodgeEffect()
    {        
        GameObject _DodgeSFX = Instantiate(gameObject, transform.position, transform.rotation );

        Destroy(_DodgeSFX.GetComponent<PlayerController>());        
        Destroy(_DodgeSFX.GetComponent<PlayerCombat>());
        Destroy(_DodgeSFX.GetComponent<WarpController>());
        Destroy(_DodgeSFX.GetComponent<Animator>());
    }
```

Comment: There are some really interesting videos on how to do that in a neat way: https://www.google.com/search?q=unity+dash+effect

Comment: My guess: Without seeing how each of these classes works this is not answerable. It sounds like you should rather create a [prefab](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Prefabs.html) of the player without these components and rather instantiate that prefab

Comment: I appreciate the links but originally I did go through quite a few of these and they weren't what I was looking for. I was following this part of a video I found https://youtu.be/QAFL1NXnqog?t=120 and while I understand that there will be large differences between my existing code and this videos existing code, they simply instantiated a copy like I did and it worked. 
I thought it might be to do with using the new input manager but if i simply instantiate a clone, everything works how expected. As soon as I remove components from the clone it breaks even though they should be unrelated?

Answer (score 0):

its because you are making a copy of gameObject. while Instantiate() returns a GameObject, it also returns whatever you put into the first section of the method. instead, make a seperate gameObject than the player in the editor, and make _DodgeSFX public so you can put the copy into the slot. Then, just instantiate that seperate GameObject and you wont have to destroy the components through script(because you remove the components in the editor), saving time

Comment: Yeah I know of that way but the issue with that one (and why I saw a video on doing it this way) is because the after image should have every property of the original such as the animation frame, the transform, the rotation and so on. If i just instantiate a prefab it would just look like a fresh t-posing model where as I want it to look like how the player was (which my method currently does do, just breaking the controls for some reason).

Answer (score 0):

Ok so from some testing I think its down to the Unity.InputSystem only allowing 1 instance of each Input to be enabled at once. When I instantiated a clone of the player, it still goes through the Enable/Awake functions before those components are destroyed, and since the Inputs on that clone were never disabled, that becomes the "main" one. If I set the main player's scripts with Inputs deactive and then active again, it all works as normal. Note that the script was still working on the main character just fine, it was only the inputs that was broken. Im still not sure why this is the case, if its a limitation of the input system, or intentional, cant seem to find documentation of this experience anywhere.